# upload image to mysql using php throws two errors

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

i want to save image into database, i tryed this code, but i got 2 errors :

> Undefined index: photo in upload.php line 27*
>
> Warning: fopen(): Filename cannot be empty in upload.php line 27*

this is the code in line 27 : `$imgfp = fopen($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'rb');`

i figured out that the image is inserted in the database:

[image]

and when i click the inserted Blob a file with exctention **.bin** is dowloaded...

why i'm getting those 2 errors ? what can i do to avoid those errors?  and is the image properly inserted ?
 and ready for other uses like loading the image from an android apps for example?

**form.html**

```
<p>
    Cette page vous permet d'ajouter une photo à une base de donnés mysql.
</p>

<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
    <input type="file" name="photo" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
</p>
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php

if(!$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
{
    echo '<p>Please Select Image to Upload</p>';
}
else
{
    try {
        upload();

        echo '<p>Image Uploaded into MySQL Database as LONGBLOB Using PHP </p>';
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo '<h4>'.$e->getMessage().'</h4>';
    }
}

function upload(){
    /*** check if a file was uploaded ***/


    /*** assign our variables ***/
    $imgfp = fopen($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], 'rb');

    /*** connect to db ***/

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=othmane", 'root', '');

    /*** set the error mode ***/
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    /*** our sql query ***/
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO images (image) VALUES (?)");

    /*** bind the params ***/
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $imgfp, PDO::PARAM_LOB);

    /*** execute the query ***/
    $stmt->execute();

}
?>
```

Comment: “Undefined index: photo” => your file is not properly loaded (yr submit fails). All other errors are consequents.

Comment: Check print_r($_FILES) in your upload function you might not be getting your posted data

Comment: I don't know. Your code is formally correct. I have tested it until line 27 and it works for me.

Comment: Put this code at top of your script: `echo ini_get( 'file_uploads' ); die();` to test if files upload is enabled.

Comment: echo ini_get( 'file_uploads' );  gives  number 1.
and i tried this : print_r($_FILES); gives me : Array ( [photo] => Array ( [name] => Chrysanthemum.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\wamp64\tmp\phpAA1.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 32717 ) )